# Viewpager2 with fragment and diffutil problem

Tags: android, android-viewpager2, android-diffutils, fragmentstateadapter

I have a problem with viewpager2.

Problem is

- There is a viewpager2 with Fragment, FragmentStateAdapter, DiffUtil
- If page is selected, update fragment list dynamically. (remove, add)
- Here is a example.
- A, B(current), C -> swipe to C -> A, B, C(current)
- Then update list with diffUtils (oldList:A, B, C(current) / newList: C, B)
- Viewpager is updated with C(current), B successfully, but B is shown(like sliding animation left to right) because its index is changed. (before: left of C / after: right of C)

Have you ever seen this problem on the Android issue tracker?

I cannot find a solution, please help.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @Roman

`val recyclerView = getChildAt(0) as? RecyclerView`
`recyclerView?.itemAnimator = null`